# Where I can find some rdf and some sparql queries to practise to write in sparql?

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, ontology

I am trying to practice myself in writing some SPARQL queries. Does anybody know where I can find the best material? Where I can find some RDF file and some tasks to try to write my own SPARQL queries. I am good with SQL, and I just need some material to learn to write in SPARQL.

Answer (score 2):

All sample RDF and queries from the O'Reilly book "Learning SPARQL" are available on the book's home page at learningsparql.com. (Full disclosure: I wrote it.)

Answer (score 1):

[data.gov](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset?res_format=RDF&_res_format_limit=0) and [DataHub](https://datahub.io/) have a lot of downloadable RDF data sets.  If a public SPARQL endpoint is available, DataHub usually lists it.  For example:  the [Rijksmuseum page](https://datahub.io/dataset/rijksmuseum) offers RDF downloads and a link to the endpoint.

[My Experiment](http://rdf.myexperiment.org/howtosparql?) has a tutorial with examples and a working endpoint.

If you download [Jena](http://jena.apache.org/tutorials/sparql_query1.html), you get their example RDF files and SPARQL queries.

[Uniprot has a SPARQL endpoint with examples](http://sparql.uniprot.org/).  The [RDF is available for download](ftp://ftp.uniprot.org/pub/databases/uniprot/current_release/rdf/).  some of the files are quite large.

There's a large number of downloadable ontologies in RDF format at the [OBO Foundry](http://www.obofoundry.org/).

[Watch this: Probe the Semantic Web with SPARQL](http://staff.washington.edu/tabrooks/SPARQL/watchThisSPARQL.htm)

[*SPARQL Cheat Sheet* Slide Deck](https://www.slideshare.net/LeeFeigenbaum/sparql-cheat-sheet)

As mentioned above: the [website](http://www.learningsparql.com/2ndeditionexamples/index.html) for Bob DuCharme's excellent *[Learning SPARQL Book](https://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ISBN=1449371434/bobducharmeA/)*